# SQL - is it bad practice to give Read-Only access to the entire company?

Tags: sql, database, vba, security

I work in my companies small IT department. I have been creating automation via VBA in Excel to pull data from SQL and put it into Excel, then dynamically format and summarize the data. The issue I am running into is the IT department does not want to give anyone outside the IT department SQL Read-Only Access. They view SQL as a privilege not a right...even if it is only Read-Only. They claim security reasons.

Just to be clear, we are NOT installing SQL on these peoples' computers nor do they have the technical understanding on how to write queries. Also, they can already view all the information on the front-end website.

I currently have to specify which database and which tables they can have access to and it takes about 1-2 weeks to give them access (they drag their feet doing the requests).

**I am not trying to vent, I am actually wondering do they have a legit concern about security and is this actually a best practice on their part?**

Comment: "....nor do they have the technical understanding on how to write queries." I think this is a good enough reason to want to prevent any access - even read-only. You don't want people who don't know how to write SQL executing queries on your database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So even if SQL is not installed on their computer and all the queries in the VBA are built by the IT department and put into the VBA code for them? So their is no way for them to run their own SQL queries directly.

Comment: Your users will have to have read access to the database if you want them to have any sort of access to the data.  Even if you use a tool that generates the SQL for them, they still have to have access to the data.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your reply as well! I agree, but I personally don't see a security issue or any issue with giving them read only access.....especially if the automations work without installing SQL on their computer. But you're saying there would still be an issue?

Comment: Saying no one outside of IT should have access to corporate data is, quite simply,  a bunch of crap. If there is a subset of data only some people should have access to, then secure it correctly.  If the database is too complex/transactional/etc, then make an easier to use reporting database.  If business users can't get to the data, what's the point in having the data?

Comment: @Andrew hahaha I totally agree! Thank you. IDK why IT is being like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst thing that could happen is a user knows just enough to connect MS Access to the database, write some poor queries, and grind everything to a halt. You should always have non-IT users access data in a safe, structured way. Especially if this database is a transactional one, and not a reporting database.

Sure, they can access all the data per business process. So then, create a nice, safe query to read all the data and dump it to Excel - if that's what the users want.

Otherwise, IT-created queries - preferably in Stored Procedures - should be reading the data and presenting it to the users.

So it's not a security issue per se. It's more an issue of "we don't want non-IT users getting crafty and bringing down the database with poorly written queries."

Answer (score 0):

I believe the connection properties to the SQL server is embedded in your VBA code, as long as the code is not visible to the user then there is no way they can query the SQL server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an SQL read only service account which you can use for Query connections. Create an Excel data connection that has the security details to connect to SQL, then your VBA hooks into that data connection.